# React component state not updating with passed props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have created an Accordion component which has data(object) and expanded(boolean) as props.
`expanded` props is used to set the expanded/collapsed state of this component passed as a prop.

```
const DeltaAccordion = ({ index, data, expanded = true }) => {
```

Accordion component also has an internal state

```
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(expanded);
```

which is used for expanding/collapsing the accordion.
Below is my complete component

Accordion.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

// styles
import styles from "./index.module.scss";

const Accordion = ({ index, data, expanded = true }) => {
  // state
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(expanded);

  console.log(data.name, `prop-val==${expanded}`, `inner-state==${isExpanded}`);
  return (
    <div
      className={`${styles.container} caption ${isExpanded && styles.expanded}`}
    >
      <div className={styles.header} onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}>
        <div>{data.name}</div>
        <div>Click</div>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.content}>
        {data.newValue && (
          <div className={styles.newValue}>
            <span>{data.newValue}</span>
          </div>
        )}
        {data.oldValue && (
          <div className={styles.oldValue}>
            <span>{data.oldValue}</span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Accordion;
```

The parent component has a list of data and it loops through the list to create an accordion for each data item.

App.js file

```
{dataList.map((data, index) => (
        <Accordion data={data} expanded={!collpaseAll} index={1} />
))}
```

#### Here goes problem

There is also a button in my App.js file which is for either expanding/collapsing all the accordions together.
But when I pass its value as prop `expanded` to the accordion component then this value is not getting applied to the internal `isExpanded` state of the accordion component.

Here is live running code at codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-nobel-qfxm1?file=/src/App.js:635-745

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `Accordion`

```
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(expanded);
```

This line will take first time(on first render) value. To assign it next time(rerender) value you need to add a `effect`

```
useEffect(() => {
   setIsExpanded(expanded);
}, [expanded]);
```

And in your case, you can use the props `expanded` directly inside `Accordion`, you dont need to take it in local `state`.

Comment: I need a local state because each accordion has it's own toggling